# Border not showing in blockquoteh bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 (4.0.0-beta.2).

```
<blockquote class="blockquote">
  <p class="mb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
</blockquote>
```

This code does not showing border on left side. Need some help.

Answer (score 2):

There is issue with `blockquote` in `Bootstrap V4 Beta`

There is no left border in the Bootstrap v4 beta

its just `.blockquote {margin-bottom: 1rem;font-size: 1.25rem;}`

So try adding it with custom css i.e.

```
.blockquote {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    border-left: .25rem solid #eceeef;
}
```

```css
.blockquote {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    border-left: .25rem solid #eceeef;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<blockquote class="blockquote">
  <p class="mb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
</blockquote>
```